# Градиентный ActionBar и статусбар

Tags: android

Ребята, как сделать такую разметку как на картинке? А именно чтобы статусбар и actionbar были также градиентом заполнены как и основная часть экрана? Кнопки, картинка по центру не интересует, а лишь то как сделать градиент на весь экран включая статусбар и actionbar[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего это невозможно сделать на всех версиях ОС, а так - просто делаете общий фон для активити/фрагмента, делаете прозрачными statusBar и actionBar и navigationBar и всё, по идее. Скорее всего будет работать только для API>=21 и для девайсов с тач-кнопками управления

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все очень просто. Создайте в папке `Drawable` разметку `gradient:`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:startColor="#000000"
            android:endColor="#797979"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Далее откройте разметку `colors` и цвет у `StatusBar` и `ToolBar` задайте как у верхнего цвета градиента:

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#797979</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#797979</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
```

И в разметке `styles` отключите тень у вашего `ToolBar:`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">...
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">...
    <item name="colorAccent">....
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
```

И в `LinearLayout` загружаемой разметки `background`ом установите `gradient:`

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
```

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробую. Спасибо. А работать будет на всех версиях андроид?

Comment: Как вам и говорили только на API > 21. Хотя если поискать библиотеки с помощью которых можно перекрашивать `StatusBar` у Api <= 19 то можно попробовать совместимости достичь